# Binomial distribution - is that correct?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

In a particular area 30% of men and 20% of women are overweight and there are four men and three women working in an office there. Find the probability that there are 2 overweight people in the office.

What I have done: P(Two fat men in the office)*P(no fat women in the office) 
                  + P(two fat women in the office)*P(no fat men in the office)
                  + P(one fat man in the office)*P(one fat women in the office)
Solved this by binomial
The final answer I got: 0.3396. 
Book's answer is 0.317

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: We'd have to see how you worked out the probabilities in your computation

Comment: @user399625 did it by binomial

Comment: We need to see your actual work in order to determine what mistakes you made, if any.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Is the idea correct though?

Comment: I expect you made an arithmetic error.  The method you propose is fine, and the answer given by the book is correct.

Comment: after going through what I have solved, I realised I had considered 3C2 as 6. So now, I have got my answer. Thanks to everyone who reviewed my working. I will have plenty of time tomorrow to write a proper answer with MathJax so that it is helpful for anyone who stumbles upon it.